# Semantic issue in jbchartview when Xcode updated to 6.3

Tags: xcode, jbchartview, xcode6.3.2

I have been using `jbchartview` in my swift project and it was working well until I updated Xcode to version 6.3.2. Now it gives a semantic issue:

> Auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'dataSource'; it will be implemented by its superclass, use @dynamic to acknowledge intention.

in `JBBarChartView.h` and `JBLineChartView.h`.

What is actually the problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of the library are you using?

This should be fixed as as version [2.8.14](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView/tree/v2.8.14) via commit: [d299cd6](https://github.com/Jawbone/JBChartView/commit/d299cd6e7e76b7c6580dfc1dfa87c7d377db087f)